# Can R# be taught to generate meaningful ToString implementations, like it is done for Java in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: resharper

R# just generates the stub. IntelliJ IDEA, on the other hand, generates a real usable implementation. The same with the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Can R# do the same for C#?

Comment: Did you try? What's the problem with what it generates?

Comment: The problem is that it is a stub. It does not generate the actual code which would combine the ToString() invocations over all of the member variables of the particular class. Believe it or not, but both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA would generate a real toString() implementation for an equivalent Java class.

Comment: Which version of ReSharper? 7.1 does it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ReSharper 7.1, I clicked in the name of a class which had two properties, and pressed ALT-Insert (Generate Code), then chose "Formatting Members". I selected both properties and clicked ok:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("IntegerProperty: {0}, StringProperty: {1}", 
                         IntegerProperty, StringProperty);
}
```

Comment: So you did not select `Generate Code --> Override methods --> ToString()` ?

Comment: No. Override methods just gives tou a bare skeleton.

Comment: Still works in 2017.1.1 with the same strange context menu naming